# How can I bind the display members of ListView columns in a user control to a custom object?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, user-controls

I have a UserControl, called b_StringBoolTemplate, that has a ListView. The ListView's items are bound to its DependencyProperty called Items. The ListView has two columns, one for a textbox and the other for a checkbox. The XAML code for the UserControl is:

```xml
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="AutoCleaner.b_StringBoolTemplate"
    x:Name="b_StringBoolTemplate1"
    d:DesignWidth="310" d:DesignHeight="374">

    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=b_StringBoolTemplate1, Path= Items}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ElementName=b_StringBoolTemplate1, Path= StringLabel}" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                 <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=StringBoolInfo, Path=Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ElementName=b_StringBoolTemplate1, Path=BoolLabel}" Width="50" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolValue, ElementName=b_StringBoolInfo}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="50" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Name="btnDeleteItem" Content="Delete"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid> 
</UserControl>
```

In the code-behind I have an object called b_StringBoolInfo which derives from a ListViewItem and has two dependency properties, called StringContent and BoolValue. I want the Textbox.Text to bind to StringContent and Checkbox.IsChecked to bind to BoolValue, so I can dynamically add items of type b_StringBoolInfo to the UserControl.

I'm also not sure if my method is the best method to go about it. Just in case it's important Binding the headers and ItemsSource to Dendency Props work fine.

Sorry If I'm a little vague. Thanks for your responses in advance.

Edit: Sorry if I didn't make it clear.
I've added items of type b_StringBoolInfo to an instance of UserControl which is in a Window. I'm trying to bind the TextBox.Text and Checkbox.IsChecked to the properties of b_StringBool but not sure how.

In the code I've written a class called b_StringBoolInfo, which derives from ListViewItem:

```
public class b_StringBoolInfo :ListViewItem
    {


        public string StringContent
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(StringContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StringContentProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StringContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StringContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StringContent", typeof(string), typeof(b_StringBoolInfo),new PropertyMetadata("String"));



        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(BoolValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BoolValueProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BoolValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BoolValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BoolValue", typeof(bool), typeof(b_StringBoolInfo), new PropertyMetadata(true));



    }
```

I've added the user control into a window, the xaml below the UserControl object, called b_StringBoolTemplate, and its items

```
<local:b_StringBoolTemplate Margin="64,67,159,145" StringLabel="Folder Location" BoolLabel="Search SubFolders?">
    <local:b_StringBoolTemplate.Items>

        <local:b_StringBoolInfo StringContent="String" BoolValue="True"/>

    </local:b_StringBoolTemplate.Items>
</local:b_StringBoolTemplate>
```

Comment: You still havent told what is **not** working.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear so I've edited the OP. I'm trying to bind the Text of the textbox to StringContent and IsChecked of the checkbox to BoolValue, both are properties of a custom object called b_StringBoolInfo.

Comment: But whatever I try to bind them it doesn't work. I also tried 'Text={Binding StringContent}' but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is whiting following lines:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=StringBoolInfo, Path=Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```

and

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolValue, ElementName=b_StringBoolInfo}" />
```

You mentioned **b_StringBoolInfo** is a variable in code behind. But, with

```
ElementName = b_StringBoolInfo
```

You tell *XAML* parser to look for an *Element/Control* within your *XAML* file with name **b_StringBoolInfo**.

To fix it,

Change those lines to following:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```

and

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolValue}" />
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, b_StringBoolInfo is a custom object not a variable, I've added the code for the class into the Original post.

Comment: I want to add items of type b_StringBool info to the UserControl, I'm trying to bind the TextBox.Text and Checkbox.IsChecked to the properties of b_StringBool but not sure how. I've added part of the xaml code of a window which has the UserControl in it.